# What way should I take with qt:all classes inherit from QObject or delete Manually after new?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

There is some problems confused me:
1.

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
//or
QLabel *label = new QLabel;
//if I forgot to set label as a child of other widget, it causing a memory leak?
```

2.

```
QList<MyClass> myList;
MyClass *my = new MyClass;
myList.append(*my);
//is necessary？
delete my;
```

So, What way should I take with qt? All classes inherit from QObject or delete Manually after new? Or using Qt smart pointer?
Please help me, thank u very very ...

Comment: You're not paying per question on SO. If you have two questions, ask two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you allocate an object in C++ depends on the intended lifetime, and Qt doesn't change this. So, yes, in case 1 that second label is leaked because its lifetime is not tied to `this`.

In csae 2, you're using an unnecessary heap allocation. Just write

```
{
  QList<MyClass> myList;
  MyClass my; // Local scope
  myList.append(my);
}
```

Or even more succinct:

```
{
  QList<MyClass> myList;
  myList.append( MyClass() ); // Unnamed object, can be moved into myList.
}
```